# how can I convert values based on condition from list in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python.
I just faced one problem, which was taken place when I tried to convert specific values from list.

```
[[20170702, 20170708],
 993,
 994,
 995,
 996,
 997,
 998,
 999,
 ...]
```

What I want is, I'd like to convert all these integers to 0 except list things.
I tried to get through this problem with using np.where and other ways but all failed.

Comment: So the desired result is `[[20170702, 20170708], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]`? Include your code. You can check if `x` is a list as follows: `isinstance(x, list)`

Comment: `eggs = [item if isinstance(item, list) else 0 for item in spam]`

Answer (score 1):

```
r = [0 if isinstance(i,int) else i for i in llist]
```

Comment: unnecessary braces... And better `i if isinstance(i, list) else 0` - that is per OP requirments

Answer (score 0):

if your list is called x then code to get desired result is:

```
new_list = [0 if type(element) != list else element for element in x]
```